# Making blob storage public and uploading to it

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Trying to upload to a blob storage using curl command

```
curl --upload-file <file> --url "https://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<file>"
```

But keep getting 'HTTP/1.1 404 The specified resource does not exist'. I made both the storage and the container public, container's access level is set to 'container', not sure what else to try. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generating a SAS token with write access and adding x-ms-blob-type header worked. Here's curl command

```
curl -H "x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob" --upload-file <file-name> --url "https://<account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<file-name>?<SAS-token>"
```

Answer (score 4):

Any public access is always read-only. There is no public (anonymous) write access to storage blobs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=portal

Comment: I see, then that means I have to use SAS token, right? I tried that but get the error 'Signature did not match. String to sign used was w'

Comment: yes, creating a SAS token with write permissions is one way